# How to convert Windows ProductType to name?

Tags: c++, winapi

The [`GetProductInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getproductinfo) function returns `pdwReturnedProductType` as a  numeric type argument.

Is there a function to convert this number to a name?

Or, can you suggest to me a really full list of such product name constants? 
The MSDN article is missing some values, like 0x59 - "Industry Pro (Embedded)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [OSEdition Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-mde2/d92ead8f-faf3-47a8-a341-1921dc2c463b) defines on MSDN, it has the numeric values you are looking for, including 0x59:

> This section provides the product enumerations for the OSEdition element.

```
#define PRODUCT_EMBEDDED_INDUSTRY 0x00000059
```

AFAIK, there is no function to convert these numeric values into human readable names.